# How to requery a form from navigation form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've struggling with this problem on my own, then with some help, then search about it; but I haven't had any luck. So I decided to ask

I have two forms in access 2007.
1. frmNavigation 
2. frmOrderList
The form frmOrderList is embedded in the  form frmNavigation. The form frmOrderList is built based on the queris which have criterias located on the form frmOrderList.
When the criterias are change the macro (after update) start run and trying to refresh the the frmOrderList.
I tried to serveral codes but it dosen't wortk for me.

```
Forms![frmNavigation]![NavigationSubform].Form![frmOrderList].Requery
Forms![frmNavigation].Form![frmOrderList].Requery
Forms![frmNavigation]![frmOrderList].Form.Requery
Forms![frmOrderList].Requery ' Works fine for the single form
```

Still the same error
Microsoft access can't find the field 'frmOredrList' referred to in your expression

Comment: I think you're missing the SubForm part of your code. Try this:
`Forms![frmNavigation].NavigationSubForm.Form![frmOrderList].Requery`

Comment: For subform it is possible to locate as `Me.NavigationSubform.Form.Requery` Keep in mind, that `NavigationSubform` in this case name of embedded object.

Comment: `frmOredrList` - is it typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good cheatsheet in russian - http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=156 I'd like to translate some points:

1. **Basic syntax** is this:

`Forms![Form1].Controls![Field1].Value`

Mention, that "." and "!" goes one by one, switches.

It is possible to do like this:

`Forms![Form1]![Field1]`

But there should not be same named different collections' objects.

2. **Addressing subform**

Correct link to the property of subform or subreport needs to address full form identifire, using Form property of control:

`Forms![Form1].Controls![Form2].Form.Controls![Field1].Value`

In this case:

- `Forms![Form1].Controls![Form2]` is a link to a **control**, where subform is displayed.
- `Forms![Form1].Controls![Form2].Form` - is a link to subform. Addressing `Form` property is required for MS Access 97, and optional for next versions.

As described, addressing to 3rd and more level subforms is constructed:

`.Controls![Form2].Form` (or `.Controls("Form2").Form` )

3. For **addressing to an object in current context**

It is recommended to use following syntax:

`Me.Controls![Field1].Value`

`NB`: name of control, that contains form can be different from form's name. It can be checked through studying `.Name` property of a control.

---

So using these instructions, your code should be following (see 2nd recommendation):

`Forms![Form1].Controls![Form2].Form.Controls![Field1].Value`

in this case

`Forms![frmNavigation].Controls![NavigationSubform].Form.Controls![frmOrderList].Form.Requery`

And this will work, only if only names of your *controls* are same as Form's names, otherwise you should correct names of control names, that are in squre brackets.